# How do i fix point in decimal value in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have code in VB.net in below:

```
me.Index = Format(Convert.ToDouble(g.Trim()), "##.##")
```

result : 120.00

how do i same thing in C#. I don't use format function in C#. I just want result will not place more then two value after point. i mean if i send value 120.120000 then result will be 12.12

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "then result will be 120.12".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "I don't use format function in C#" but of course you *could* use `string.Format`. However, using `double.ToString` would probably be simpler:

```
Index = Convert.ToDouble(g.Trim()).ToString("0.##");
```

(I've changed the leading `##` to `0` to ensure that there's *always* a leading digit, so you don't get ".5" for example. Obviously if you *really* want the leading digits to be optional, change it to `"#.##"`. I don't see a benefit in using `##` as a prefix though.)

However:

- This will use the current culture's decimal separator; is that what you want, or do you *always* want to use `.`?
- If the decimal representation of the number is important, you may well not want to use `double` at all. Are you sure you shouldn't be using `decimal`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
decimal.Round(yourValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you use this

```
var value = 2.346;
var str = value.ToString("0.00");
```

or

`decimal.Round(yourValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`  //as in msdn site which rounds a decimal value to a specified precision.

or  use Round function like this

```
decimal a = 1.994444M;

Math.Round(a, 2);
```